# Tools for Informix

Tags: informix

Are there any tools available for Informix, similar to 'Query Analyzer' for SQL Server?

Answer (score 6):

We needed a Query Analyzer-like tool for an Informix project some time ago, and settled on [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/), which is Java based, so it's completely platform independent (Windows, MacOS, Linux, etc).  About half of the development team at our company uses Macs, so that was a requirement.  On top of that, it can connect to any database through JDBC (29 different databases, according to the website).

I've used it extensively on MySQL, SQLServer and Informix, and can confirm it works great on all of them.  Before RazorSQL, I was using MySQL tools, and SQLServer Management Studio on a VM, but having a single tool to work with any DB you can throw at it is pretty nice.  Also, for accesing Informix from a Mac, it's one of the few options available.

Answer (score 5):

Not knowing anything about 'Query Analyzer' for SQL Server, I could be being misled by its name, but...

- The [Open Admin Tool](http://openadmintool.org/) has support for analyzing query performance in a number of ways.
- [Server Studio](http://serverstudio.com/) (SSJE) has some support for query analysis and performance monitoring.
- The basic server provides SET EXPLAIN to describe a query plan.
- There are numerous performance analysis tools - such as ON-Stat and the pseudo-tables in the SysMaster database.
- There are also some ancient tools such as 'ON-Perf' distributed with IDS that may help too.

Comment: Hey thanks Jonathan, actually we are looking for a tool to query Informix.

Answer (score 2):

We use [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/), a nice tool which supports different databases.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan's answer is excellent so I'll just confirm that
[Server Studio](http://serverstudio.com/) is a great albeit overpriced product.

Also to simply (and freely) run Informix Queries you could use [Eclipse SQL Explorer](http://www.sqlexplorer.org/)